# How to plot the outside of a 3D shape in Python Plotly without defining its faces?

Tags: python, plotly, isosurface

I'm trying to plot some 3D shapes in Python Plotly. For the sake of practicing, I was trying to plot a cube.

I tried the `Isosurface` command since I'm only interested in the outside of the shape, but surprisingly enough, the output was not a cube.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np 

x=[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
y=[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
z=[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

myisosurf = go.Isosurface(x=x,y=y,z=z,value= np.ones(len(x)))
fig = go.Figure(data=myisosurf)
fig.show()
```

[image: plotly isosurface output when plotting a cube]

I did get it to work with the `Mesh3D` command (with a little help from [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3000)), but the fact that it also requires settings for parameters of `i, j, k`, makes me prefer a more straightforward method. Especially when working with more complex shapes than a cube, it would be very hard to set the `i, j, k` parameters.

```
i= [7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 6]
j= [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 6, 3]
k= [0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 6, 5, 5, 7, 2]

my3dmesh = go.Mesh3d(x=x,y=y,z=z, i=i, j=j, k=k, intensity = np.linspace(1, 1, 8, endpoint=True),name='y')
fig = go.Figure(data=my3dmesh)
fig.show()
```

[image: Cube with Mesh3D]

How can I get Python Plotly to show the outside of a shape without manually defining its faces through `i,j,k` parameters?

Comment: Additional search keyword: "convex hull".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Adreas Deak's comment, it seems that the [alphahull parameter](https://plotly.com/python/reference/mesh3d/#mesh3d-alphahull) of the `Mesh3D` command can direct Plotly to show the convex hull of the coordinates in the input.

Without the alphahull parameter (or with `alphahull = -1`) Delaunay triangulation is used to compute the faces around the coordinates, using the `i, j, k` parameter values.
With `alphahull = 0`, the convex hull method is used to compute the faces around the coordinates, resulting in only the 'outside' of the shape, without the need for setting `i, j, k` parameters.

so:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np 

my3dmesh = go.Mesh3d(x=x,y=y,z=z, alphahull = 0, intensity = np.linspace(1, 1, 8, endpoint=True),name='y')
fig = go.Figure(data=my3dmesh)
fig.show()
```

[image]